# Clicking on an admin link for a site where I'm not a mod displays the mod agreement page instead of a 404

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, moderators

When I click on a link to an admin page on a site where I'm not a moderator I see a *Moderator Agreement* page instead of a 404 page.

Example (using my own UserID):

Clicking on https://stackoverflow.com/admin/show-user-votes/3536342 displays:

> [image]

The URL gets redirected to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement?ret=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fadmin%2fshow-user-votes%2f3536342
```

Note that I'm a *moderator* on Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Positive repro and I'm not a mod anywhere.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as Bitter and was similarly able to reproduce.

Comment: Also repro incognito/without any login credentials.

Comment: I'm a new user, and I get a positive repro.
Same in the Android app. (I know... I just had to check)

Comment: Seems to have been fixed. I get an 404 now.

Answer (score 1):

Looked into this with a few people and we weren't able to reproduce. If this comes up again, please let us know!